# Как сделать lookup-method в Spring с помощью аннотаций

Tags: java, spring

В Spring есть возможность объявить lookup-method. С помощью xml это настраивается следующим образом:

```
<bean id="simpleBean"
      class="test.spring.SimpleBean"
      scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="testLockupMethodService"
      class="test.spring.TestLockupMethodService">
    <lookup-method bean="simpleBean" name="getSimpleBean"/>
</bean>
```

Первый бин

```
package test.spring;

public class SimpleBean {

    private static int count;

    private int id;

    public SimpleBean() {
        id = count++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SimpleBean{" +
            "id=" + id +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Второй бин

```
package test.spring;

public abstract class TestLockupMethodService {

    public void doSomething() {
        getSimpleBean();
    }

    public abstract SimpleBean getSimpleBean();
}
```

Как можно настроит такое же с помощью аннотаций?

Comment: Вуаля: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5192

Answer (score 2):

Привет! Я так понимаю вам нужно это.

```
@Configuration
public class AppContex{
    @Autowired
    private SimpleBean someBean;
    @Bean
    public TestLockupMethodService testLookupMethodService(){
       return new TestLockupMethodService(){
              public SimpleBean getSimpleBean(){
                  return someBean;
              }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего так

```
public @Component class MySingletonBean {

    public void showMessage(){
        MyPrototypeBean bean = getPrototypeBean();
        //each time getPrototypeBean() call
        //will return new instance
    }

    public @Lookup MyPrototypeBean getPrototypeBean(){
        //spring will override this method
        return null;
    }
}
```

источник: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/using-lookup-method.html